# Interface Exception whitout casting using as keyword

Tags: c#, interface

I tried to create a generic class that receive a generic parameter based on interface and the code thre an exception

so I tested and I have the following

```
interface InterfaceA { }
interface InterfaceB<T> where T:InterfaceA { }
class ClassA : InterfaceA { }
class ClassB : InterfaceB<ClassA> { }
```

the basic test

```
InterfaceB<InterfaceA> my_object_1 = new ClassB(); // Not Working (Compile error)
InterfaceB<InterfaceA> my_object_2 = (InterfaceB<InterfaceA>)new ClassB(); // Not Working (Throw Exception)
InterfaceB<InterfaceA> my_object_3 = new ClassB() as InterfaceB<InterfaceA>; // Working but still null
```

Someone can explain me why there is a problem with my_object_1, my_object_2 and my_object_3?

Comment: What exactly do you call "working"? I'd expect `my_object_3` to be null after that code...

Comment: looks like if it doesn't throw exception and compiles OK, it's working?

Comment: yes, my_object_3 is null

Comment: `InterfaceB<InterfaceA> != InterfaceB<ClassA>` for `ClassB` because it could use methods defined in `ClassA` that aren't defined for `InterfaceA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that `new ClassB() as InterfaceB<InterfaceA>` doesn't throw an exception, but it does return `null`, which is [what `as` does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx) when it can't cast. This is because `ClassB` isn't usable as an `InterfaceB<InterfaceA>`, no matter how you try to cast it.

It **is** implicitly usable as an `InterfaceB<InterfaceA>`, however, if you put `out` before `T`:

```
interface InterfaceB<out T> where T:InterfaceA { }
```

This makes [`T` covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233059.aspx), which means that, e.g. an `InterfaceB<ClassA>` can be used as an `InterfaceB<InterfaceA>` (but not vice versa).

The compiler will error out if `T` cannot be covariant, because you take `T` as an input somewhere. With such an interface, you can't logically use `ClassB` as an `InterfaceB<InterfaceA>`, for the same reason that working with a `List<string>` as an `IList<object>` doesn't make sense: you could try to do something impossible, like add a non-string object to a string list.

Comment: Thanks, that works, the bad news, is that I wanted to replace an old messaging system without having to rewrite/deploy an old lib and this part is in the old section